# How to explain the buffer overflow in this program?

Tags: c, buffer, overflow

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int check_authentication(char *password){
    int auth_flag = 0;
    char password_buffer[16];
    strcpy(password_buffer, password);
    if(strcmp(password_buffer, "password1") == 0){
        auth_flag = 1;

    }
    return auth_flag;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(check_authentication(argv[1])){
        printf("Access granted!");
    }
    else{
        printf("Access denied!");
    }
}
```

When I enter a password that has 29 bytes or more, I get access granted.
In this case, maybe it needs 16 bytes(password_buffer) + 12 bytes("password") = 28 bytes.

And when I write `char password_buffer[12];` it just needs password to have more than 13 bytes and I get access granted.

I don't understand, where is "password" ?

Comment: My english is not good.. ! my bad.

Comment: Your program does not check any bounds. It just copies the first passed argument from the program call. You won't need the `strcpy` just compare whether arg[1] equals "password1".